# Why $urandom_range is returning the same value?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, register-transfer-level, test-bench

I'm running a test bench with UVM. In one of the component's `run_phase()` task, I do a `fork...join_none` to start the following loop, which runs through the entire simulation:

```
fork
   forever @(posedge trigger) begin
      force dut.a = $urandom_range('h00,'hFF);
      force dut.b = $urandom_range( 'h0, 'hF);
      force dut.c = $urandom_range('h00,'hFF);
      force dut.d = $urandom_range( 'h0, 'hF);
      force dut.e = $urandom_range('h00,'hFF);
      force dut.f = $urandom_range( 'h0, 'hF);
   end

 ...
 some other stuff
 ...
join_none
```

The thing is the signals *a*, *c* and *e* get forced to the same value. Same for *b*, *d* and *e*.

If there's a new trigger posedge later, new values do get randomized and forced, but again I get `a == c == e` and `b == d == e`.

It seems as if `$urandom_range` is being called just once for each parameter's choice (0 to FF, and 0 to F), and the return value re-used for the three `force` commands.

---

EDIT: I was able to reproduce the issue on a minimal TB: http://www.edaplayground.com/x/4_ph

It looks like an issue with the vendor I'm using, choosing other tools the issue goes away.

---

EDIT 2: I haven't figured out exactly why this happens, but it seems to be related to the fact that *force* statement is like a continous assignment (ie if the RHS signal changes in the future, the forced LHS will follow it until the *force* is *release*d, it's not like an '=' assignment).

So my guess is that the problem lies in using the returned value of the function as a RHS. (I don't know which lifetime this returned value has)

The solution in my case was to save the $urandom value to a variable with static lifetime, and then force that variable to the RTL (as J Reid suggested)

Comment: How close is the code you posted to what you actually executed?

Comment: @dave_59 I edited the post with some more context. I'm trying to re-create it in EDA Playground but I'm having trouble with my account for the moment

Comment: Same issue Sept. 2021. Sad there was no resolution.

Comment: @MahmoudMaarouf check mi "EDIT 2" above, that fixed the problem and the explanation sounds reasonable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a class with random variables and constraints???

```
// outside of the test-bench
class my_stimulus;
    rand bit [7:0] a, c, e;  // can be logic if you like
    rand bit [3:0] b, d, f;  // rand won't give X or Z

    constraint c1 { 
        unique {a, c, e}; 
        unique {b, d, f};       
    }       
endclass;   

// inside the actual testbench 
my_stimulus to_dut = new; 

fork
   forever @(posedge trigger) begin
    if (!(to_dut.randomize()) $error;
    force dut.a = to_dut.a;
    ...
    force dut.f = to_dut.f;
   end
...
join_none
```

The unique constraint will either cause an error or give you unique values every time. Having the size specified removes the need to set bounds but that can be done as well with another constraint.

Answer (score 1):

Two issues with your code.
The first you have the arguments to $urandom_range reversed; it is (*max*,*min*), and the *min* is optional defaulting to 0. Some simulator will figure this out, but it is not standard.

The second issue is since you are repeatedly forcing the same expression. the simulator might not see that as new expression and does not call $urandom again. Try putting a `release` statement before each `force`.

```
 forever @(posedge trigger) begin
      release dut.a; force dut.a = $urandom_range('hFF);
      release dut.b; force dut.b = $urandom_range('hF);
      release dut.c; force dut.c = $urandom_range('hFF);
      release dut.d; force dut.d = $urandom_range('hF);
      release dut.e; force dut.e = $urandom_range('hFF);
      release dut.f; force dut.f = $urandom_range('hF);
   end
```

Comment: Good catch with the inverted range.
I tried releasing the signals, but no luck. Actually, when the block is re-triggered, signals do update to new random values... it's just that the values chosen are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a very similar problem with "urandom_range" as the OP using NCSIM. However, "urandom" worked just fine. There shouldn't be any reason that "urandom" shouldn't work in your case instead of "urandom_range" (assuming that "urandom" works correctly of course). The result of "urandom" will simply get truncated.

BACKGROUND INFO: Just in case anyone is curious, I ran into an error in NCSIM with regards to "urandom_range" (but not "urandom") where the first call to the function would always return the minimum specified value no matter what. But all subsequent calls worked just fine.

Comment: I added some more information on my question, hope it helps